# which one better for css (Bootstrat OR own CSS), Animation, component for start new project in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I started new web project in angular 6, which one better for the future perspective like code management, code structure, animation, loading time, responsive, project size, development time, security.

I researched,

which one better from bellow,

for design,

- **Bootstrap** or
- **Own CSS**

for component,

- **ngx-bootstrap** or
- **MDBootstrap** or
- **KendoUI** or
- **Angular Material**

for animation,

- **AngularAnimation** or
- **Animate.css + WOW.js** or
- **AOS** or
- **write own animation**

I created project for testing using this combo below,

- **Angular** + **Bootstrap** + **for animation** (animate.css,wow.js, AOS.css) + **for Component** (ngx-Bootstrap) +  **any css like** (libeicon.css, fontawasome, responsive).
- **Angular** + **Bootstrap** + **write own css for animation** + **for component** (design own)  + **any css like** (libeicon.css, fontawasome, responsive).
- **Angular** + **Bootstrap** + **for animation** (angularAnimation) + **for Component** (Angular Material) + **any css like** (libeicon.css, fontawasome, responsive).

I don't know which combo is better for the project, it's important for me because this project is a huge concept (long time period), Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think last one is better. You can use Angular with Angular material and bootstrap with third party library like fontawasome.